# DatagramSocket: queue output vs simple send

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, datagram

I'm programming an udp server. Right now, when it is necessary from client code to send data, every thread representing a "connection" sends a datagram to a blocking queue, and the server thread then reads every datagram and sends it.

Peeking into DatagramSocket.send i see it synchronizes over the datagrampacket, but i cannot tell if at the end of the day would be more performance-wise to queue everything vs directly sending it. With the latter i suspect i could use direct bytebuffers.

***So my question is: Would it be more wise in terms of performance to queue everything or directly send it?***

Comment: You should try it out and profile them (and post the results here). My wager would be that there's very little performance difference, so it would be a design choice instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send it directly. The socket send buffer already is a queue. The complication of another queue and another thread adds no value at all.  Just another thing to go wrong.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Could this be applied to receive? i have one thread that listen to every datagram received and depending on its address it will alert one or another thread to process the payload, creating new threads in case no thread exist with that address.

Comment: It depends on the time it takes to service each request. If it's low, do it all in one thread.